# I have a text voice with polly, could I send this in a twilio message to whatsapp?

Tags: python, twilio, whatsapp

I'm creating an app, I'm having problems when I try to send audio to twilio message and display in whatsapp.

I tried with the audio in mp3 and using media url, but it's not returning anything.

The code basically is this:

```
path = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/compartamosdemo-50264.appspot.com/o/10557652_confirmacion.mp3?alt=media&token=d22c70ba-b123-4670-8a11-4adef74b0699"

message = ""
try:
    message = client.messages.create(
        body='Nuevo mensaje',
        from_='whatsapp:+141....',  # Twilio phone number
        to='whatsapp:+57319....',  # WhatsApp recipient phone number
        media_url=[path]
    )
except Exception as e:
    app.logger.error("Error en messages: %s", e)

return str(message)
```

If I delete the media_url field, I receive the text message, but What I want is to receive the audio file in a voice response.

Comment: Is this part of a function or what?  Where are you returning the message to?

Comment: Yes it's a part of a class, don't need a return message because when We call the client.messages.create send the message to whatsapp. The problem is that I don't know how can I send instead of text an audio (with text works fine). I review the twilio documentation but not find any similar.

Comment: solved, using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76010749/sending-ogg-file-to-whatsapp-using-twilio